# case sensitive doesn't work in sluggable on server with uppercas

Tags: laravel, case-sensitive, slug

I am using [sluggable](https://github.com/cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable) package in Laravel. When I store same letters with upper or lower cases, it dosen't know they are the same! for example 'myFlower' and 'myflower' assigns different cases. I will be pleasure if anybody has ideas?

```
class testController extends Model
{
    use Sluggable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'slug',
    ];

    public function sluggable()
    {
        return [
            'slug' => [
                'source' => 'name'
            ]
        ];
    }

    public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        return 'slug';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to add a new accessor and use it as a source like this:

```php
class testController extends Model
{
    use Sluggable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'slug',
    ];

    public function sluggable()
    {
        return [
            'slug' => [
                'source' => 'lowercase_name'
            ]
        ];
    }

    public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        return 'slug';
    }

    public function getLowercaseNameAttribute() {
        return strtolower($this->name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `\config\sluggable.php` file, there is a method function. The last line of the function is:

```
return preg_replace(array_keys($map), array_values($map), $string);
```

Replace the `$string` with `strtolower($string)`. The line should be like this:

```
return preg_replace(array_keys($map), array_values($map), strtolower($string));
```

This will cause all letters become lowercase before being used to make slugs, so that two same words with different letter cases will not be considered as two different words.